# Не получается обработать нажатие ListView

Tags: android, android-billing, viewholder

Создал адаптер, который обрабатывает нажатие на кнопку на пункте в ListView.
Код:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    final ru.vpiska.shop.ShopAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(this.layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ru.vpiska.shop.ShopAdapter.ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ru.vpiska.shop.ShopAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    final Shop shop = shopList.get(position);

    viewHolder.titleView.setText(shop.getTitle());
    viewHolder.priceView.setText("Цена: " + shop.getPrice());


    viewHolder.linkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bp.consumePurchase(shop.getProductId());
            bp.purchase((Activity) getContext(),shop.getProductId());
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}
```

И соответственно код ошибки при нажатии кнопки:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: ru.vpiska.app.AppController cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                                                           at ru.vpiska.shop.ShopAdapter$1.onClick(ShopAdapter.java:71)
```

Comment: ru.vpiska.shop - вот это название)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ругается на `(Activity) getContext()`
В данном случает getContext возвращает Context а не Activity

Передать Activity  в конструктор адаптера и использовать переданный экземпляр(так же как передаете shopList).

Comment: Было бы неплохо узнать, как исправить это, ошибку я и сам понял, решение найти не получается

Comment: дополнил ответ.